# asp.net listview bind to object

Tags: asp.net

on wcf service

```
public class Response
{
    public string ID { get; internal set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }

    public Message()
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Now;
        Message = "";
        ProcessName = "";
    }
}
```

asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
    binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;

    EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["wcfserviceURL"]));
    Wcfservice.wcfserviceClient wcfservice = new Wcfservice.wcfserviceClient(binding, endpoint);

    Wcfservice.Response response = wcfservice.ReturnResponse();

    //I need to bind the response.Messages to a listview. It should display data in 3 columns DateTime, Message and ProcessName
}
```

I used the datasource wizard and it created the following. But I don't know what to do next for the data to be displayed

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1">
</asp:ListView>
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="Wcfservice.Response" EntityTypeName="" 
    TableName="Messages">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your page load, where you're trying to bind the ListView:

```
LinqDataSource1.DataBind();
```

Comment: it throws error:
Could not find a property or field called 'Messages' on the data context type 'Response' of LinqDataSource 'LinqDataSource1'.
It's not even loading the page.